# Heroku deployment issue with Zero to Mastery final project "smart-brain"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku, deployment

So I am finishing up a full stack project that was deployed in heroku and connected through github for automatic deployment. The front-end works fine but I am receiving errors both on heroku and the developer tools for Chrome when registering users. The back-end worked fine locally but after deployment I am now receiving an "application error" page.  On chrome it kicks out:

*Access to fetch at 'https://facial-recognition-machine.herokuapp.com/register' from origin 'https://facerecognitionbrain-sk.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."*

On heroku cli after using "heroku logs -a"
[Heroku CLI Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScqqS.png)

These are the repositories on my github of the front end and back end for reference.

[Front End](https://github.com/skelleher2/facerecognitionbrain)

[Back End](https://github.com/skelleher2/smart-brain-api)

I'm relatively knew to this so thank you in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I figured it out from heroku's deployment documentation of Node.js.

I needed a .gitignore file that contained

/node_modules
npm-debug.log
.DS_Store
/*.env

It was also suggested to delete the node_modules and npm install again.